# what is a token , what is a lexeme

Tags: compiler-construction, token, grammar, formal-languages

i've been watching a video on how compilers break down code and converts them into tokens , i came across this part which kind of means that the lexer actually figures out lexemes , which are closer to the words of a sentence and tokens are kind of like verbs . can anybody just explain the heirarchy and what sits where,
if token is like a verb are there types of tokens and lexemes are just examples of these token types, like run is an example of a verb
[the video](https://youtu.be/QXjU9qTsYCc?t=247)

Comment: Tokens are lexemes with context and metadata. That's literally it. Lexemes are meaningless strings of characters. Tokens give them meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Here we have our input:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Let's get the lexemes as a list now:

```
["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog", "."]
```

Please remember that these are **lexemes**, meaningless strings of characters. `"The"`, although in English, has a meaning, in our example, it currently conveys no meaning or information. It is *simply "T", then "h", followed by "e"*. Nothing else.

The next step is to look at these lexemes and give each of them a meaning, creating **tokens**. Often, the meaning changes depending on the given context.

So for `"quick"`, we could say it is:

```
Token
    type: "ADJECTIVE"
    lexeme: "quick"
```

Notice that we have now associated a meaning to this lexeme, its type, which is an adjective. Here is what a `"fox"` could be:

```
Token
    type: "NOUN"
    lexeme: "fox"
```

However, tokens are not useful by themselves. We need a meaningful structure from the list of tokens. That's what the next step is usually for: *parsing*.

In our example, a parser might turn our input into the following:

```
Sentence
    type: "SIMPLE"
    subject: Subject
        adjectives: [
            Token
                type: "ADJECTIVE"
                lexeme: "quick"
            Token
                type: "ADJECTIVE"
                lexeme: "brown"
        ]
        noun: [ ... ]
    ...
```

Now we've got a useful data structure from a 1 dimensional input! Fascinating! It's important to note that tokens can contain more information than just a type and the lexeme. They could, for example, also contain the line and column the lexeme was found.

---

You also may not realize it, but this is how you read! You are always reading in the list of lexemes, giving them meanings, then creating a structure from that and interpreting what the meaning of the entire sentence was.